# Slide button back and forth between two points

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipangesturerecognizer

I'm trying to use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to slide a button between two points (like a volume slider). The following code allows me to slide the button back and forth, but the button doesn't stop at the same point every time (i.e., when I slide it to the right, sometime it stops where it's supposed to, sometimes it stops +/- 10 pixels from where it's supposed to). What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void)handlePan:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:self];


    // 1
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {
        // if the gesture just started, record current center location
        _originalCenter = self.sliderButton.center;
    }

    // 2
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // move the checkmarks and main label based on touch
        //CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self];

        // move slider button
        if (location.x < 70 + 178 && location.x > 70) {
            self.sliderButton.center = CGPointMake(location.x,  _originalCenter.y);
        } 

        // determine whether the item has been dragged far enough to initiate a removal
        if (location.x > 170 + 70) {
            _draggedToEnd = YES;
        } else {
            _draggedToEnd = NO;
        }
    }

    // 3
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        if (_draggedToEnd) {
            // notify the delegate that this item should be deleted
            [self buttonDraggedToEnd];
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: How about when the location is outside the points, you place it on the closest point? So if x<70, put it on x=70.

Comment: What Tom Irving suggest is the way to do this!

Comment: I can't see the part of the code where you fix the view location after the gesture is finished. Is it part of `buttonDraggedToEnd` ? If so, please post the related code.

Comment: That did it, Tom, thanks! Add it as an answer and I'll accept :)